# pfSense no access from lan to wan

Tags: windows-server-2008, local-area-network, pfsense, wide-area-network

Can anyone please help me ? Probably the answer is already somewhere in the forum, but unfortunately I have not found it until now.
Since two days I fight to have access to the internet across a pfSense-firewall from one virtual server and can't find the barrier or the problem-cause. Hope so much that a forum-member can help me. For example i can't ping to google.de.

By the way, I'm a bloody beginner, it's my second firewall and my first pfSense...

Many thanks for every help.

:) Marvin

Here is my configuration...:

```
        +-------------------+
        |    Client_Win7    |
        +--------+----------+
                 | LAN 10.10.10.10
                 |
                 | Ethernet IP
                 |
        +--------+----------+         
        |     Gateway       |
        +--------+----------+
                 |
        +--------+----------+         
        |    Internet       |
        +--------+----------+
                 |
        +--------+----------+         
        |     Gateway       |
        +--------+----------+
                 | LAN 5.5.5.1
                 |
                 | Ethernet IP
                 |
                 |
                 | WAN 5.5.5.5/24
                 | Static IPv4
                 | Upstream Gateway 5.5.5.1
                 | unchecked Block private networks
                 | unchecked bogon networks
        +--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+         
        |   virtual machine                                                                                                 |
        |   Firewall_pfSense                                                                                               |
        |   V:2.1.3-RELEASE                                                                                              |
        |   enabled DNS forwarder                                                                                      |
        |   Automatic outbound NAT rule generation                                                            |
        |   Rules: LAN.1 Action:Pass Interface:LAN Protocol:any  Source:any Dest: any          |
        |   Rules: WAN.1 Action:Pass Interface:WAN Protocol:TCP  Source:any Dest: any       |
        |   Rules: WAN.2 Action:Pass Interface:WAN Protocol:ICMP Source:any Dest: 5.5.5.5 |
        +--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                 | LAN 10.0.0.1/24
                 | Static IPv4
                 | unchecked Block private networks
                 | unchecked bogon networks
                 |
                 |
                 | Ethernet IP
                 |
                 | LAN 10.0.0.2/24
                 | Gateway 10.0.0.1
                 | DNS 10.0.0.1
        +--------+------------+
        |   virtual machine   |
        |   Server_Win2008    |
        +---------------------+
```

I can use from Client_Win7 the pfSense-webConfigurator with `http://5.5.5.5`
I can use from Server_Win2008 the pfSense-webConfigurator with `http://10.0.0.1`
I can ping from Server_Win2008 to `10.0.0.1`
I can ping from Client_Win7 to `5.5.5.5`
I can ping from Firewall_pfSense to `10.0.0.2`
I can ping from Firewall_pfSense to `173.194.70.94`
I can use on Server_Win2008 nslookup google.de and get `173.194.70.94`
I can use on Server_Win2008 tracert google.de and get: 1 first hops `10.0.0.1` and after this many "Request timed out"
I can't ping from Server_Win2008 to `173.194.70.94`

Comment: I hope you are aware that your Firewall_pfSense actually does not filter anything. You have a WAN rule to allow ALL TCP.. ?

Comment: I have no WAN rule because the request comes from LAN,why do you think I need one ?

Comment: You have a PASS rule for ALL TCP Traffic that comes from WAN. So essentially you DISABLED your firewall, and it's a ROUTER now. :)

Comment: I have a similar situation -- I'm guessing it has something to do with the firewall as well. However the guy above that said you turned the firewall into a router? That's what he WANTS (for now).. don't you see? He wants to allow clients to access WAN, THEN he can setup firewall. Right now, he can't even get clients to access WAN ... so if he disables firewall, he'll know it's not pfsense and something else. Someone help this man.

Comment: How was this solved